# Matrix Rotation Unexpected Result

Tags: python, matrix

I am a newbie for Python, and encountered a problem about matrix rotation.
Following is my code

```
def rotateMatrix(matrix):
    if matrix == []:
        return []
    row, col = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    res = [[0]*row]*col
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            res[col-1-j][i] = matrix[i][j]
    return res

mat = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
print rotateMatrix(mat)
```

The print result is [4,8,12] for all 4 rows!!! I just don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

This issue is with

```
res = [[0]*row]*col
```

Because you are repeating a single list `col` times you get this behaviour.

```
>>> res = [[0]*3]*4
>>> res
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> res[0][0] = 1
>>> res
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Which is the same as this.

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = x
>>> x.append(5)
>>> x
[5]
>>> y
[5]
```

Instead you should use list comprehension if you want a one-liner.

```
res = [ [ 0 for r in range(rows) ] for c in range(col) ]
```

Or

```
res = [ [ 0 ] * rows for c in range(col) ]
```

Comment: @beat me by a min ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just saw somewhere to generate zeros matrix with [[0]*r]*c, and didn't realise the problem here